# Android apk sign revocation date warning what means

Tags: android, certificate, apk, sign

I have a warning on apk signing (generated by `jarsigner -verify`), see below. What is meant by `revocation date` - what can be revoked (certificate?) by whom in what case? I created apk via standard Android Studio 1.5 `build - generate signed apk` menu and creating new key storage.

```
Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2141-02-03) or after any future revocation date.
```

Answer (score 1):

Revocation date is the expiration date of your APK example (15-01-2035) and you can no longer use the release-key to update that same application.